# Sandbox solutions are not enabled on the SharePoint server form - Infopath 2010?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, infopath, sandbox-solution, forms-services

I have designed an Infopath form, picture button is placed inside the repeat table. When the button is clicked, I want to remove the current row of the repeat table, so have added the code mentioned below

e.Source.DeleteSelf()

it works if I test the Infopath form locally however unable to deploy it into the SharePoint 2010.

it throws the below error:
Sandbox solutions are not enabled on the SharePoint server form.
To continue, contact a site collection or farm administrator to publish the form template as an administrator-approved form template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

User form templates that contain code can be published by site collection administrations to form libraries as sandboxed solutions. For more information about sandboxed solutions, [see Sandboxed solutions overview (SharePoint Server 2010)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721992%28v=office.14%29.aspx). Form templates that require full trust or use a data connection that is managed by an administrator must be deployed by an administrator. For more information about administrator-approved form templates, see [Manage administrator-approved form templates (SharePoint Server 2010).](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262921%28v=office.14%29.aspx)